# Postman/Newman junit report customization

Tags: junit, postman, newman

I'm using postman and newman to perform automated  tests and I do a JUnit export in order to exploit them in TFS. 
However, when I open my .xml report, failures are indicated as follows:

```
-<failure type="AssertionFailure">
    -<![CDATA[Failed 1 times.]]>
</failure>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to customize the "Failed 1 times." information in order to pass more relevant data about the failure (ie. json body error and description)

Thank you

Alexandre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found out how to proceed (not a clean way but sufficient for my purpose, so far):

I impact the file `C:\Users\<myself>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\lib\reporters\junit\index.js`

Request's data and response can be recovered from 'executions' object:

`stringExecutions = JSON.stringify(executions); //provide information about the arguments of the object "executions"`

from this I can take general information by json-parsing this element and extracting what I want:

```
jsonExecutions = JSON.parse(stringExecutions)
jsonExecutions[0].response._details.code // gives me the http return code,
jsonExecutions[0].response._details.name // gives me the status,
jsonExecutions[0].response._details.detail //gives a bit more details
```

Error data (at test case/testsuite level) can be recovered from the 'err.error' object:

```
stringData = JSON.stringify(err.error); jsonData = JSON.parse(stringData);
```

from that I extract the data I need, ie.

```
jsonData.name // the error type
jsonData.message // the error detail 
jsonData.stacktrace // the error stack
```

by the way, in the original file, stack cannot be displayed as there is no 'stack' argument in error.err (it is named 'stacktrace').

Finally failure data (at test step/testcase level) can be recovered from the 'failures' object:

```
stringFailure = JSON.stringify(failures); jsonFailure = JSON.parse(stringFailure);
```

from this I extract:

```
jsonFailure[0].name // the failure type 
jsonFailure[0].stack // the failure stack
```

For my purpose, I add response details from jsonExecutions to my testsuite error data, which is much more verbose in the XML report than previousely.

If there is a cleaner/smarter way to perform this, do not hesitate to tell me, I'll be grateful

Next step : do it clean by creating a custom reporter. :)

Alexandre